# Efficient way to multilinearize in Maple

Tags: maple

I wish to use Maple to multilinearize polynomials. For example, given $xy^2z^4+x^3$ as input, I want $xyz+x$ as output.  Is there a specific command for this?

Comment: I am probably treading in deep water here, but does global linearization make sense? Do you mean that the outputted linearization is around a point? If so, which? And is the output linear? Please excuse my possible ignorance.

Comment: I want a procedure that replaces any term of the form $x_1^{n_1}\cdots x_k^{n_k}$ with $x_1\cdots x_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very best way to do this in Maple is probably the `evalindets` command which lets you apply a transformation to type-selected subexpressions:

```
poly := x*y^2*z^4+x^3;  
linearpoly := evalindets(poly, 'name^posint', v->op(1,v));
```

The `op` command takes the operands of an expression, the first operand of an expression like `x^n` is the base of the power: `x`.

So the above code walks the expression tree and replaces every `x^n` term with `x`.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to eliminate the powers, I suppose you could do this with a regular expression. In Maple this is done with the `StringTools` package.

```
with(StringTools):
have := x*y^2*z^4+x^3;                                ## Input

have_string := convert(have,string);                  ## Make it a string
want_string := RegSubs("\\^[0-9]" = "",have_string);  ## Remove "raised to number"
want := parse(want_string);                           ## Back to equation
```

Comment: You're almost always going to be better off operating directly on the Maple expressions rather than converting to a string.